# A direct proof to Fermat's Little Theorem

Tags: number-theory

Hello everyone I think I've proven Fermat's Little Theorem which I know it to be:

$$x^p \equiv x \pmod p$$

I use the same trick I used to calculate sum formulas which I shared yesterday here.

Proof: If $p=2$ the result is obvious (if a number is odd then it's square is odd and the same for even numbers), let's say $p$ is an odd prime for the proof.

Notice that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{x} i^p-{(i-1)}^p=x^p \tag{*}$$

This is the property we will use, let's expand that ${(i-1)}^p$ part, by binomial theorem we have

$$(i-1)^p=\sum_{k=0}^{p} {p \choose k} \cdot i^{(p-k)}(-1)^k$$

Let's expand this for the first and last term to get:

$$(i-1)^p={p \choose 0} \cdot i^{(p-0)}(-1)^0+\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}{p \choose k}.i^{(p-k)}(-1)^k+{p \choose p} \cdot i^{(0)}(-1)^p$$

Here as $p$ is an odd prime $(-1)^p=-1$, if we substitute this in we get:

$$(i-1)^p=i^p+ \left(\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}{p \choose k} \cdot i^{(p-k)}(-1)^k \right)-1$$

If we substitute this in $(*)$ we get:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{x}\left( i^p-\left(i^p+\left( \sum_{k=1}^{p-1}{p \choose k} \cdot i^{(p-k)}(-1)^k \right)-1\right)\right)=x^p$$

If we do the algebra we get:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{x}\left(- \sum_{k=1}^{p-1}{p \choose k} \cdot i^{(p-k)}(-1)^k \right)+\sum_{i=1}^{x}1=x^p$$

We can see that $\sum_{i=1}^{x}1=x$, substituting this in gives us:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{x}\left( \sum_{k=1}^{p-1}{p \choose k} \cdot i^{(p-k)}(-1)^{k+1} \right)+x=x^p$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{x}\left( \sum_{k=1}^{p-1}{p \choose k} \cdot i^{(p-k)}(-1)^{k+1} \right)=x^p-x$$

Now here we know that when $p$ is a prime and $k$ is not $p$ or $0$, the combination in ${p \choose k}$ is always divisible by $p$, in that sum every combination satisfies this so everything that is summed there are divisible by $p$, consequently so is their sum, then we have the following:

$$p|\sum_{i=1}^{x}\left( \sum_{k=1}^{p-1}{p \choose k} \cdot i^{(p-k)}(-1)^{k+1} \right)$$

which means $p|x^p-x$ and we know that in modulus this implies

$$x^p \equiv x \pmod{p}$$

Is this proof valid? Thank you for reading.

Comment: This looks valid, although I think you've dropped a negative sign just after substituting into your (*) equation. This doesn't change the validity ($p \mid n \iff p \mid -n$), but you may wish to correct it.  EDIT: Also, it could use some grammatical reworking; I suspect you're not a native English speaker? Either that or writing very, very informally.

Comment: What if $x<0$? The equation $(*)$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thank you @EricSnyder, you are most certainly right, I am not a native speaker but I will be working on it. Also thanks for pointing out that negative sign, I adjusted the power of the $(-1)$ accordingly.

Comment: @jjagmath, if we have a negative $x$ we take a positive equivalent of it in modulus $p$ here, I did not mention that, thank you!